# Linking SDL2 statically without pulling in X11 dynamically

Tags: static-libraries, sdl-2, static-linking

I am using SDL2.0.12 on Ubuntu 20.04. I link statically to [SDL2](https://www.libsdl.org), adding the linker argument:

**`sdl2-config --static-libs`**

So far, so good.

However, the SDL static link flags pull in a slew of SDL2 dependencies, that *are* linked dynamically:

```
$ sdl2-config --static-libs
-lSDL2 -Wl,--no-undefined -lm -ldl -lasound -lm -ldl -lpthread -lpulse-simple -lpulse -lX11 -lXext -lXcursor -lXinerama -lXi -lXrandr -lXss -lXxf86vm -lwayland-egl -lwayland-client -lwayland-cursor -lxkbcommon -lpthread -lrt
```

Which leaves me with a slew of dynamic dependencies that may not be present on other linux distributions:

```
readelf -d foo | grep NEEDED
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libGL.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libSDL2-2.0.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so.2]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libasound.so.2]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpthread.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpulse-simple.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libpulse.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libX11.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libXext.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libXcursor.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libXinerama.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libXi.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libXrandr.so.2]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libXss.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libXxf86vm.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libwayland-egl.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libwayland-client.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libwayland-cursor.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libxkbcommon.so.0]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [librt.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libstdc++.so.6]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libgcc_s.so.1]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so.6]
```

How can I get rid of these dynamic dependencies?

For starters, how could I link statically against X11?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this, but I heard that SDL2 that comes from Ubuntu repos is configured to unconditionally require some of the dependencies (as you see), while building it yourself from sources with default settings would make it decide what to load at runtime, depending on what libraries are present in the system. (Then you don't need to statically link X11 or whatever.) E.g. for my custom-built SDL2 `pkg-config sdl2 --libs --static` reports `-lSDL2  -Wl,--no-undefined -lm -ldl -lpthread -lrt`, and similarly `readelf -d libSDL2-2.0.so.0` only reports those libraries and no X11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDL development libraries provided in Ubuntu have many dynamic dependencies. Even for the static `libSDL2.a` library.

When building SDL2 from source, you can avoid these.

For instance, to avoid a dependency on X11, you would feed it these autoconf flags:

```
./configure \
        --enable-x11-shared \
        --enable-video-x11 \
```

The `--enable-x11-shared` will actually make SDL2 link in that dependency at run-time. And not, as you may expect, link against X11 `.so` dependencies.